# How to watch exception when there is no catch in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception, uncaught-exception

Is it possible to determine which exception was occurred when it was catched by `finally` only?

Below is excerpt from standard ThreadPoolExecutor code:

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            Runnable task = firstTask;
            firstTask = null;
            while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
                runTask(task);
                task = null;
            }
        } finally {
            workerDone(this);
        }
    }
```

I.e. here is no `catch`. My debugger stops on `workerDone()` call indicating RuntimeException occurred, but since here is no exception variable I see no way to know error message or something.

Comment: ... you can't.  Put in a `catch(Throwable t){t.printStackTrace;}` if you want to see what the exception is.

Comment: @bdares, this is library code and I don't want to recompile it

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add an "exception breakpoint" in the debugger for uncaught exceptions.  Typically, this is a tab right next to the "variables" tab in the Debug perspective.

Comment: That would be the `Breakpoints` view. Check the view's toolbar for a J with an exclamation point.

Comment: Debugger already stops. I just need to know what exception caused it, read it message or disable stopping.

Answer (score 1):

Not only for eclipse.
You can use the Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)
If you can recompile, then do it inside the 'run' method.
If not, ASAIK, even if you do that in the main thread, you will catch the exceptions in the "inner" threads.

[setUncaughtExceptionHandler Example](http://www.codingdiary.com/developers/developers/diary/javaapi/java/lang/SampleCode/setUncaughtExceptionHandlerExampleCode.html)

Comment: The Example you posted is quite usesless. This is its output: `You crashed thread Thread-3
Exception was: java.lang.RuntimeException: Thrown from Thread
java.lang.RuntimeException: Thrown from Thread
 at de.utils.SetUncaughtExceptionHandler.run(SetUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:16)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)`